# Activity loading after 5-6 seconds in Android

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, android-viewpager

**I am working on an app and here it takes 5-6 sec to load the activity when I open the app, I know it is because of the dates I have got of 10 years in the viewpager but how do I fix that and load it quick?**

Ignore this:
It is a handbook describing every type of fish then known to occur in the British Isles. Yarrell was a London bookseller and newsagent with the time and income to indulge his interest in natural history. He was a prominent member of several natural history societies, had an extensive library and collection of specimens, and a wide network of naturalist friends who helped him garner material for his writings

**MuscleActivity.java**

```
package com.example.freefit;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ViewPager2 myViewPager2;
    ViewPagerDateAdapter ViewPagerDateAdapter;
    private final ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);



        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(new Date());
        c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -5);
        Date startDate = c.getTime();
        c.add(Calendar.YEAR, +10);
        Date endDate = c.getTime();

        // Create Calendar Objects that represent start and end date
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
        start.setTime(startDate);
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
        end.setTime(endDate);

        ArrayList<String> date = getList(start, end);


        Log.d("Start", startDate.toString());
        Log.d("End", endDate.toString());


        ViewPagerDateAdapter = new ViewPagerDateAdapter(this, date);

        myViewPager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
        myViewPager2.setAdapter(ViewPagerDateAdapter);
        myViewPager2.setCurrentItem(((date.size() + 1) / 2) - 1);


        Log.d("size", String.valueOf(date.size()));


        myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                Log.e("Selected_Page", String.valueOf(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        });

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getList(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
        ArrayList<String> date = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (startDate.compareTo(endDate) <= 0) {
            date.add(getDate(startDate));
            startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        return date;

    }

    public String getDate(Calendar cld) {

        String curDate = cld.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + (cld.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cld.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).parse(curDate);

            curDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return curDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move getList off the main thread.  Show a loading screen (such as a spinner) until it's done, then populate the recycler with the results.  You're lucky you aren't going ANR if it's taking that long.

In fact, rethink everything about the getList function.  WHy do you need to precompute all the strings?  You don't.  You can just return a list of Dates, and compute the string value of it when they're displayed.  Even better, since they're all 1 day after the other-  you can not have an array at all.  YOu can calculate the number of days between start date and end date, and just calculate even the date only when it needs to be displayed.  None of this needs to be calculated up front.  Adapters don't need to be arrays, all they need to be able to do is calculate the number of items in it (which can be done by math here) and figure out the element for a given index (which can be done for only the items needing to be displayed, and can be done via calendar manipulation).